# How to pass basic auth and other header info to proxy server using gRPC?

Tags: authentication, proxy, grpc, nginx-reverse-proxy, grpc-go

I am using rest API and currently doing the API call using below where my Nginx(proxy) using this as login validation

`{URL:http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/admin Method:GET Body: Headers:map[Authorization:Basic dXNlcjE6dGVzdDE= apikey:user1 content-type:application/json] }`

how do I pass the same credentials in gRPC, it seems we can not send as usual headers as the rest call, is there any way to send header details in gRPC? so that my proxy validates the cred and sends to my server

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:"+gRPCserver_port, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can not connect with server %v", err)
    }
```

I am using go lang, can you pls help

Answer (score 0):

[grpc-go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go) supports two types of credentials:

- [TransportCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.47.0/credentials#TransportCredentials): these apply to the whole connection between client and server
- [PerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.47.0/credentials#PerRPCCredentials): these can be applied on a per-RPC level

If you are interested in passing authentication related headers from client to server, you would most likely use per-RPC credentials. These can be attached on a per-RPC basis using the [PerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#PerRPCCredentials) call option. They can even be applied for the whole connection using [WithPerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WithPerRPCCredentials) dial option. Also, note that some per-rpc credentials can only be transferred on a secure channel. If that is the case, then you would have to configure TransportCredentials (other than the insecure credentials that you mention in your example).

Please refer to examples in the grpc-go repository for configuring [encryption](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/encryption) and [authentication](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/authentication). Hope this helps.